# Request Entity Too Large (JasperServer / Apache / Tomcat)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jasperserver

I get following error when I try to access some JasperReports Server pages:

> Request Entity Too Large The requested resource
>   /jasperserver/olap/viewOlap.html  does not allow request data with GET
>   requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the
>   capacity limit.

I checked the Apache log files and got following error in mod_jk.log

> [Thu Nov 10 10:25:00 2016][8964:3876] [error]
>   ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (517): failed appending the
>   query string of length 7417

I already tried many different ways to solve it.

I added the maxHttpHeaderSize and max_packet_size attributes to the ajp connect of Tomcat (server.xml):

```
<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" max_packet_size="65536" />
```

Also I added the LimitRequestLine, LimitRequestBody, LimitRequestFieldSize and LimitRequestFields to the Apache httpd.conf file (added it to the end of the file without any VirtualHost):

`LimitRequestLine 65536
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitRequestFieldSize 65536
LimitRequestFields 10000`

I am still getting the error above.

I also found some suggestions to add the max_packet_size to the workers.properties of Apache. But if I add the attribute I get a HTTP 400 error and a white page. That's why I commented the property in workers.properties:

`#worker.jasper.max_packet_size=65536`

I restarted all services after changing the configurations.

When I access the same pages via HTTP-Connector of Tomcat (http://HOSTNAME:8081/jasperserver/..) it works fine. Only when I access it via AJP-Connector of Apache (http://HOSTNAME/jasperserver/..) I get the error. So I think there should be any problem with the AJP-Connector.

Apache: 2.4.12
JasperReports Server: 6.2.1
Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.14:

Does anyone have a suggestion what I have to do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The attribute in server.xml for Tomcat has to be
`packetSize`
and not 
`max_packet_size`

See also documentation [AJP Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/ajp.html)

After renaming it, it works fine.

Here are my configurations:

Tomcat server.xml:

`Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" packetSize="65536"`

Apache workers.properties:

`worker.jasper.max_packet_size=65536`

If you get afterwards the error:

> Request-URI Too Long
>
> The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

You have to set following attributes in Apache httpd.conf file:

`LimitRequestLine 65536
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitRequestFieldSize 65536
LimitRequestFields 10000`

I hope this answer helps others too.

Comment: Adding "ProxyIOBufferSize 65536" too to Apache was the solution